# Printing array elements gives wrong output

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf

I am trying to print a pattern that consists of a digit and dollar signs based on the user input. I ask the user to select an option for a pattern and then I ask for a size of the pattern. I use swap to create the pattern, so If the user were to select option 1 and then input a size of 4 they should get something like:

> 4$$$ $4$$ $$4$ $$$4.

Right now I am just trying to get `patternOne(0` working. I am having trouble printing out the elements of the array I create in my `patternOne()` function. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int option, size;
    do {
        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("1. Pattern one\n"
               "2. Pattern two\n"
               "3. Pattern three\n"
               "4. Pattern four\n"
               "5. Quit\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        do {
            printf("Please enter your choice (between 1 & 5): ");
            fflush(stdout);
            scanf("%d", &option);
        }while(option < 1 || option > 5);

        switch(option) {
            case 1:
                do {
                    printf("Choose a pattern size (between 2 & 9): \n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    scanf("%d", &size);
                }while(size < 2 || size > 9);
                patternOne(size);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Testing case 2.");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("Still testing.");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Testing case 4.");
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("Thank you for playing.\n");
                break;
        }

    }while(option != 5);

    return 0;

}

void patternOne(int size) {
    char ar[size];
    ar[0] = size;
    for(int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        ar[i] = '$';
    }
    int x = 0, y = 1, temp, iter = 0;
    while(iter <= size) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            printf(j);
        }
        temp = ar[x];
        ar[x] = ar[y];
        ar[y] = temp;
        x++;
        y++;
        iter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. There are several items in this code you should be concerned about, most notable the incorrectly executed [**`printf`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) in your `patternOne` function, for which you provide no format string.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you need to have a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of your function `patternOne()`, otherwise, you'll get an implicit definition issue.

Then, inside your `patternOne()` code,

```
 printf(j);
```

should be, at least

```
printf("%d", j);
```

Otherwise, you'll pass an invgalid type of argument to [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, you can simplify the logic for your `patternOne()` function by using the following algorithm

1. Create the `char` array
2. memset to `$`
3. run a loop, iterating from `0` to `n-1`, setting the `n` value.
4. continue to 2, until loop runs out

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want, I modified the code as per **Sourav Ghosh** suggested,

replace your pattern one function with this,

```
void patternOne(int size) {
    char ar[size];
    memset (ar, '$', size);

    for (int h=0; h<size; h++){
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            if(h==i)
                printf("%d",size);
            else
                printf("%c",ar[i]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

This is the output i got

[[image: This is the output i got [1]]